# PWM generation for inverter by Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, mosfet

Can I generate a PWM signal for a Mosfet driver using a saw tooth wave and sine wave through Arduino ?

Comment: You could  add a DAC chip. Or use some resistors to create an R-2R resistor ladder.

Comment: PS I think most inverters use regular PWM (at a higher speed), and smooth the output. Using mosfet in a none-saturated is inefficient, and will make them run hot.

Comment: Read the datasheet of your inverter: What should the PWM signal look like? What frequency? Duty cycle? If you add this information to your question, it would be possible to provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can very easy generate an PWM Output with an Arduino:

```
void setup()

{

  pinMode(pwmPin, OUTPUT);   // sets the pin as output

}



void loop()

{

  analogWrite(pwmPin, yourWantedValue);  // analogWrite values from 0 to 255

}
```

> On most Arduino boards (those with the ATmega168 or ATmega328), this
>   function works on pins 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, and 11. On the Arduino Mega, it
>   works on pins 2 - 13 and 44 - 46. Older Arduino boards with an ATmega8
>   only support analogWrite() on pins 9, 10, and 11.
>
> The Arduino Due supports analogWrite() on pins 2 through 13, plus pins
>   DAC0 and DAC1. Unlike the PWM pins, DAC0 and DAC1 are Digital to
>   Analog converters, and act as true analog outputs.

Visit [quote origin](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite) for more Information.

Comment: Note that the PWM frequency is quite low: 490 or 977 Hz depending on the pin. The OP should check the datasheet of the inverter to make sure those frequencies are OK.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, none of the boards have a DAC on them, with the exception of the arduino Due. Thus, Unless you have the Due board, it is not possible.
If you have a due board, and are interested in generating wave functions, then check out here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DueSimpleWaveformGenerator